# Sniff and monitor already running server

Tags: web-services, fiddler, sniffing

I deployed a webservice on a webserver hosting IIS 7.5.
I tried to monitor the incoming and outcoming traffic with software like Fiddler or Charles, but probably I missed some concepts.

My server has no particular configuration, so I thought all was really easy, but I cannot monitor at all any traffic.
The client of the ws is another device, in the same network.

Can you suggest me how to monitor what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is a proxy; it monitors all of the traffic that's sent to *it*.

Typically, that means that you should configure **the client's** proxy settings to point at Fiddler (which Fiddler does automatically for the PC it's running on) and then all the traffic is captured.

If you want to run Fiddler **on the server** to watch *incoming* requests, you'd need to [configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/usefiddlerasreverseproxy).

Alternatively, in the very latest version of Fiddler you could use Wireshark or NetMon to capture the inbound packets on the server at the network level, then click File > Import > Packet Capture in Fiddler to import those packets and parse them as HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, for of all you made the situation clever. In my scenario I have the control of client (call it C) and the server (call it S). Which is the fastest and easiest solution to monitor the traffic between them? If I configure C to send the traffic to Fiddler, how can I reach S?

Comment: I could reach from IE on C the address of my webservice (http:\\server:8888\MyService), and in Fiddler I can see the records logged. But, If I modified my client to call http:\\server:8888\MyService instead of http:\\server\MyService, I receive an error. 
Why is working from browser and not from the client?

Comment: What "error" do you receive? Also, I trust you're using the proper slashes for HTTP, i.e. `//` (not `\\`)